# Unable to connect to secured wi-fi from Nexus 7 running Ubuntu Touch 13.04

Tags: wireless, networking, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, wpa2

I have put Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 7, using MultiROM. But I am unable to connect my Ubuntu Touch tablet to my home wi-fi (WPA2 Personal). After I type in the password and click OK, it shows the list of available wi-fi networks again. It does not connect to the wi-fi, for which I have entered the correct password. So, I have to enter the password again. But still, it does not connect. Just shows the list of available wi-fi networks again.

NOTE: My password is very long. I am not sure if the wi-fi connection is timing out by the time I have entered the password?

I have adb access to the device. So, if anyone needs any more information to diagnose the issue, I gladly provide it!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problem, after entering the correct password I was not able to access the wifi. However after going to system settings and doing a factory reset and system reset it connected straight away without re-entering any password. Unsure what the problem was but that was my fix.