# Unable to connect to new Wi-Fi Networks

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, aquaris

I am unable to connect to new wi-fi networks on my BQ Aquaris E5 Ubuntu Edition.

Nothing happens after entering the network password.
Previously used networks worked fine.

Resetting the phone did not help. [It seems to have solved the same problem for someone else though.](https://askubuntu.com/q/306734/581820)

I have used `ubuntu-device-flash` to flash the latest stable ubuntu touch image as well as build r42 from `ubuntu-touch/rc/bq-aquaris.en`:

`ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/rc/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap --recovery-image recovery-vegetahd.img --wipe`

Even that did not help.

Since the problem occurs after entering the password I suspect that there might be a problem with storing the password. Are the Wi-Fi settings stored somewhere where they are not affected by re-flashing the OS even with `--wipe`?

Comment: Is it an `a/b/g/n` or `ac` network? 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz?

Comment: @Android Dev I am trying to connect to a Thomson TWG870 which according to https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Thomson_TWG870 is a/b/g/n.

Comment: @Android Dev It is 2.4GHz.

Comment: When I started to use my Nexus 4 with Ubuntu Touch, the same happend for me. But after some restarts and doing some other stuff with the device it suddenly worked. So just do a reboot and give it a try this morning.

Comment: @eDeviser Thanks for your comment. I have experienced this problem for weeks now. I have rebooted countless times and re-flashed the OS three times. I also do a lot of random stuff on the device since it is my only phone. Just rebooted again, unfortunately no change yet.

Comment: Are you by any chance experiencing this issue: http://pad.lv/1588126

Comment: @pomsky Yes! Thank you very much! Flashed OTA-10, Wi-Fi works now.  Hopefully this will be fixed in OTA-13. Why don't you write an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: until a fix is released, somewhere I found a workaround that worked for me.  I copy and paste the password from the notes (or any other text) app and it connects without problem.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you. I can confirm your workaround on my OTA-12 phone.

Comment: @hanspeteriv I'll go ahead and throw it in the answers to increase visibility and provide context to my investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [issue](http://pad.lv/1588126) started appearing after the OTA-11 update & is supposed to be fixed with the upcoming OTA-13 update. Meanwhile you may use OTA-10 image as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around that seems to work on OTA-12 at least on my Nexus 4 which is documented at
[How can I get a Nexus 4 running 15.04 OTA-12 to connect to a particular wi-fi network when it won't accept the password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808288/how-can-i-get-a-nexus-4-running-15-04-ota-12-to-connect-to-a-particular-wi-fi-ne)
The main bullet point is to enter the password in a note or text application then copy and paste it into the network manager connection dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'forgetting' the last network where the device was connected, tick the box in the settings to get the connection dialog up with the desired network and then 'connect'. That is how I recovered after having experienced what you have, reported the problem to bq.com and getting NO answer.